# Passing params to nested directives with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, scope, directive

I have an object `data` in the `MainCtrl`. This object is used to pass data to directives `first-directive` and `second-directive`. Two-data binding is neccesary in both cases.

For `first-directive`, I pass the complete object `data` but for `second-directive` I want to pass `numbers` object (`scope.numbers = scope.dataFirst.numbers`).

**The problem:**

When I do `<div second-directive="dataFirst.numbers"></div>`, and I check if `dataSecond` is an object, it returns `true`.

But when I do `<div second-directive="numbers"></div>` and I check if `dataSecond` is an object, it returns `false`.

In both cases if I do `console.log(scope)` the `scope.dataSecond` property is shown.

**The question:**

Why does this occur and what's the correct way to pass params to directives?

**EDIT:**
The idea is making reusable directives and this implies that they can't depend on others directives.

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    numbers: {
      n1: 'one',
      n2: 'two'
    },
    letters: {
      a: 'A',
      b: 'B'
    }
  }
})

.directive('firstDirective', function () {
  return {
    template: '<div class="first-directive">\
      <h2>First Directive</h2>\
      {{dataFirst}}\
      <div second-directive="dataFirst.numbers"></div>\
      <div second-directive="numbers"></div>\
      </div>',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      dataFirst: '=firstDirective'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('first directive')
      console.log(scope)
      scope.numbers = scope.dataFirst.numbers;
    }
  };
})

.directive('secondDirective', function () {
  return {
    template: '<div class="second-directive">\
      <h2>Second Directive</h2>\
      {{dataSecond}}\
      <div class="is-obj">is an object: {{isObj}}</div>\
      </div>',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      dataSecond: '=secondDirective'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('second directive');
      console.log(scope)
      
      // <div second-directive="XXXX"></div>
      // if 'numbers' returns undefined
      // if 'dataFirst.numbers' returns the object
      console.log(scope.dataSecond); 
      
      scope.isObj = false;
      
      if(angular.isObject(scope.dataSecond)){
        scope.isObj = true;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.first-directive {
  background: #98FFDA;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.second-directive {
  background: #FFA763;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.is-obj {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h2>MainCtrl</h2>
    {{data}}

    <div first-directive="data">
    </div>

    <div second-directive="data">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll repeat what others before me said - that the `link` function of `firstDirective` is a **post**-link function that runs ***after*** the `link` function of `secondDirective`, and so `scope.numbers` is not yet assigned the object `scope.dataFirst.numbers`.

However, a solution that tightly couples two directives via `require` seems sub-optimal to me.

Instead, to make sure that a scope property is properly assigned in the parent before inner/child directives run (like `secondDirective`, in this case) is to use a **pre**-link function in the `firstDirective` (instead of a **post**-link)

```
link: {
  pre: function prelink(scope){
      console.log('first directive')
      console.log(scope)
      scope.numbers = scope.dataFirst.numbers;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yb64bHr14VPhcXhKm5zG?p=preview)**

Answer (score 8):

My solution to this would be to have the second directive inherit the data object attribute from the first directive.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    numbers: {
      n1: 'one',
      n2: 'two'
    },
    letters: {
      a: 'A',
      b: 'B'
    }
  }
})

.directive('firstDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div class="first-directive">\
      <h2>First Directive</h2>\
      {{dataFirst}}\
      <div second-directive></div>\
      <div second-directive></div>\
      </div>',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      dataFirst: '=firstDirective'
    },
    controller: function firstDirectiveController($scope) {
      return $scope;
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('first directive')
      console.log(scope)
      scope.numbers = scope.dataFirst.numbers;
    }
  };
})

.directive('secondDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div class="second-directive">\
      <h2>Second Directive</h2>\
      {{dataSecond}}\
      <div class="is-obj">is an object: {{isObj}}</div>\
      </div>',
    replace: true,
    require: '^firstDirective',
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, firstDirectiveController) {
      console.log('second directive');
      console.log(firstDirectiveController.dataFirst.numbers);
      
      scope.dataSecond = firstDirectiveController.dataFirst.numbers;

      scope.isObj = false;

      if (angular.isObject(scope.dataSecond)) {
        scope.isObj = true;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.first-directive {
  background: #98FFDA;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.second-directive {
  background: #FFA763;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.is-obj {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h2>MainCtrl</h2>
    {{data}}

    <div first-directive="data">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's a good answer if you know the nested order of the directives in the html. My idea is making reusable components (like dropdowns) and this implies that you don't know the order. For example, if you try to put the `second-directive` in the  `<body>`, it doesn't work because it needs the `first-directive`. Thank you :)

Comment: This solution definitely works (although, it unnecessarily tightly couples the two directives together), but a good answer should be more than just code.